# Can I pair and use two microphones with my iPhone 6+?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, microphone

I want to connect two bluetooth microphones to my iPhone 6+ to record a conversation during a walk/hike.  I know the iPhone can handle up to 7 connections, but can only output sound to one device at a time (unless a splitter is used).  Can there be two inputs via bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you do not need bluetooth microphones to record a conversation.

iPhones have a built-in app called voice memos which, assuming you have a relatively new iPhone, should be able to pick up the conversation fairly well if you just set the iPhone to record and put it in your pocket.